# Join BeautifulSoup Contents with map and lambda

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to scrape the web contents and clean up the format

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import lxml
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning'
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
fetched_text=' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text.soup.find_all('p'),soup))
```

It has an error like below:
[image]

This code was originally found from a youtube tutorial like this:

```py
fetched_text=' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text.soup.find_all('p')))
```

But it was complained about map() was not using correctly.
[image]

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: `[x.text for x in soup.select('p')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are more confortable using list comphension:

```py
fetched_text=' '.join([p.text for p in soup.find_all('p')])
```

or you can do it with map, remember that map waits a function and an iterable:

```py
fetched_text=' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('p')))
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much! Just curious, if I do want to use lambda and map, what this code should look like? I am still learning. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I added the example with map

Comment: remember that you can mark a question as solved to show that it's solved